# Wrong visualization with Primefaces RowExpansion and Column Priority

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces DataTable with RowExpansion with column priority for responsive design. But when I'm opening the row expansions with the row toggler the relation between the columns of the original datable get lost. The effect is, that a column with a lower priority gets hidden, but the space of this column stays empty, so the priority handling doesn't work correctly with the expanded table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please always state PF version…

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use PF >= 5.3, you most likely (99.9% sure) are running into a not supported combination of features. There is no official list of supported combinations however, but this does not mean it is a bug, just a not supported combination of features. If you create an mcve, see http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and post that in the PF github as a feature request, it might become a (still not official since there is no list) supported combination.

You could try fixing it yourself, but it most likely (again 99.9% sure) requires changes to the PrimeFaces source

Comment: Thank you. I will make a feature request, so maybe it will be in a future version available.